# Unwanted remount attempt of UBIFS rootfs during boot

Tags: linux, mount

I have an ARM system using buildroot-2011.05 - Linux 2.6.38.7. The board uses a NAND flash and to get around a problem with squashfs not liking bad blocks I changed the root file system to use read-only UBIFS instead.

The system now boots Ok but I am concerned by and can't find the source of a kernel message about remounting the UBI volume R/W:

```
[    1.540000] UBIFS: read-only UBI device
[    1.630000] UBIFS: recovery needed
[    1.700000] UBIFS: recovery deferred
[    1.710000] UBIFS: mounted UBI device 0, volume 0, name "rootfs"
[    1.710000] UBIFS: mounted read-only
[    1.720000] UBIFS: file system size:   14321664 bytes (13986 KiB, 13 MiB, 111 LEBs)
[    1.720000] UBIFS: journal size:       9033728 bytes (8822 KiB, 8 MiB, 71 LEBs)
[    1.730000] UBIFS: media format:       w4/r0 (latest is w4/r0)
[    1.740000] UBIFS: default compressor: lzo
[    1.740000] UBIFS: reserved for root:  0 bytes (0 KiB)
[    1.750000] VFS: Mounted root (ubifs filesystem) readonly on device 0:14.
[    1.760000] devtmpfs: mounted on dev
[    1.770000] Freeing init memory: 104K
**[    2.060000] UBIFS: cannot re-mount R/W - UBI volume is R/O**
```

It uses barebox init (no sysvinit) but I think the message is generated before it gets to this.
There are posts on the net about the UBIFS bug when remounting R/W after an error but this isn't the case, it's mounted read only to begin with. All I can think of is there could be default kernel behaviour to mount the rootfs r/w.

Kernel bootargs:

```
 console=ttymxc0,115200 rootfstype=ubifs ro ubi.mtd=3 root=ubi0:rootfs otg_mode=host lpj=514048 mtdparts=mxc_nand:256k(barebox)ro,128k(bareboxenv),3M(kernel),16M(rootfs)ro,16M(flash),-(misc)
```

Relevant parts of inittab and fstab:

```
    ::sysinit:/bin/mount -t proc proc /proc
    ::sysinit:/bin/mkdir -p /dev/pts
    ::sysinit:/bin/mount -a

    proc            /proc           proc     defaults                                                       0                       0
    devpts          /dev/pts        devpts   defaults,gid=5,mode=620                0                       0
    tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs    defaults                                                       0                       0
    tmpfs           /var            tmpfs    defaults                                                       0                       0
    sysfs           /sys            sysfs    defaults                                                       0                       0
    /dev/mtdblock4  /mnt/flash      jffs2    noatime
```

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

Do `make menuconfig` for buildroot.

Then in the 'System Configuration' menu, make sure that 'remount root filesystem read-write during boot' is not selected.

Answer (score 1):

I was tracking a similar issue. I specified a read-only rootfs on the kernel cmdline and saw UBIFS mounting as read-only during startup, but / was mysteriously read-write by the time I got to a shell.

In my case, the **/etc/init.d/mountall** script turned out to contain the line

```
/bin/mount -o remount,noatime,nodiratime /dev/root /
```

In turn, the generation of that script was controlled by a file system configuration option in my board's SDK. The details may vary depending on your setup, but check your init scripts and check any configuration options that generate them.